# Get Session in Spring AOP

Tags: spring, session, thread-safety, aop, spring-aop

I am no sure if my codes is thread safe,anyone can help?

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {

   @Autowired
   private HttpSession session;


   @Before("...")
   private void myMethod() {
       seesion.getId();
   }

}
```

Because MyAspect's scope is default(singleton),so many request exsits at same time and also many session.OK,Which session I get in my code?Is it thread safe?Or it's a wrong code,if it's wrong,how can I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right, it's OK.

1. Your `MyAspect` should be registered as bean anyway.
2. It doesn't matter is it AOP Aspect or not: the dependency injection infrastructure the same.
3. Now about `HttpSession`.
   This object isn't registered as bean, but for him Spring provide a trick - `WebApplicationContextUtils.SessionObjectFactory`. This object is registered as

`beanFactory.registerResolvableDependency(HttpSession.class, new SessionObjectFactory());`

And when the injection works it wraps `SessionObjectFactory` with `Proxy` to invoke real methods on demand from `ThreadLocal<RequestAttributes>` variable. That mean that each call of your `MyAspect.myMethod` does the stuff for concrete `HttpSession`, if your current Thread is a Servlet Thread, of course.

So, the answer to your question: yes, it is **thread safe**.